# On Ubuntu 20.04 accessing shared folder in Virtualbox Windows Guest causes guest to reboot

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04

Using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa, install virtualbox:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack
```

Now load a Windows 10 VM:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/

Click the Download Virtualbox VM

Now, create a shared folder between this VM and the Ubuntu host. Place a bunch of files on this folder.

Now, on Windows 10, try to access this folder. The VM will reboot.

This doesn't happen in Ubuntu 18.04

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest version of Virtualbox...

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1`

If you can't install virtualbox-6.1, then follow the instructions [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) to add the repo to your system, then retry the install.

---

Add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list. According to your distribution, replace `<mydist>` with 'focal', 'eoan', 'bionic', etc.

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <mydist> contrib
```

Then do...

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.1
```

Comment: Yeahp, this is right! I had to reinstall guest additions too after doing this and it worked!  I had a previous version and my guest additions was hitting this bug here -> https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/18766?cversion=0